# Python 3 PyQT4 зависает интерфейс во время выполнения программы

Tags: многопоточность, python-3.x, pyqt4

Есть скрипт и интерфейс к нему написаный на pyqt4.
Во время выполнения функций скрипта интерфейс программы подвисает и (не отвечает). Ни какие данные до окончания выполнения программы не обновляются в интерфейсе например w.textbrowser.append . После выполнения всех функций данные появляются. Проблема в том что имя интерфейс все равно приходится следить за ходом выполнения из IDE.

Подозреваю что тут нужно использовать некие потоки /. Threads но я с ними не знаком. Верно ли моё предположение и если да то что советуете почитать в этом случае

Answer (score 1):

выполнять код в отдельных потоках, передавая данные в интерфейсчерез qt cигналы и слоты

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import threading, time


class Wind(QtGui.QWidget):
    Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.Signal.connect(lambda s: self.resize(s[0], s[1]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
    QApp = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Wind()
    w.show()

    # отдельный поток
    def resize():
        for i in range(1000):
            w.Signal.emit([i, i])  # изменяем размер из другого потока
            time.sleep(0.1)
    threading.Thread(target=resize).start()

    QApp.exec()
```